# What's the difference between &C::c and &(C::c)?

Tags: c++

Test code in below and I put the output info in comment. 
I was using gcc 4.8.5 and Centos 7.2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

class C 
{
    public:
        void foo() {
            printf("%p, %p\n", &C::c, &(C::c)); // output value is 0x4, 0x7ffc2e7f52e8
            std::cout << &C::c << std::endl;    // output value is 1
        }
        int a;
        int c;
};

int main(void)
{
    C co;

    printf("%p\n", &C::c);              // output value is 0x4
    std::cout << &C::c << std::endl;    // output value is 1

//    printf("%p\n", &(C::c));   // compile error, invalid use of non-static data member 'C::c'

    co.foo();

    return 0;
}
```

1. According to [C++ operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)，the `::` operator has higher precedence than the `&` operator. I think `&C::c` is equal to `&(C::c)`, but the output says otherwise. Why are they different?
2. `&(C::c)` causes a compile error in main but not in the `foo` function，why is that?
3. The value of `&C::c` is different in `printf` and `std::cout`, why is that?

Comment: You cannot `printf` a pointer to member value. `%p` is for regular pointers only.

Comment: @n.m. Even worse, `%p` is for `void *` only.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

C++ distinguishes two forms of operands to the `&` operator, lvalues in general and (qualified) identifiers specifically. In `&C::c` the operand of `&` is a qualified identifier (i.e. just a name) whereas in `&(C::c)` the operand is a general expression (because `(` cannot be part of a name).

The qualified identifier form has a special case: If it refers to a non-static member of a class (like your `C::c`), `&` returns a special value known as a "pointer to member of C". See [here for more information about member pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_members).

In `&(C::c)` there is no special case. `C::c` is resolved normally and fails because there is no object to get a `c` member of. At least that's what happens in `main`; in methods of `C` (like your `foo`) there is an implicit `this` object, so `C::c` actually means `this->c` there.

As for why the output is different for `printf` vs. `cout`: When you try to print a member pointer with `<<`, it is implicitly converted to a `bool`, yielding `false` if it's a null pointer and `true` otherwise. `false` is printed as `0`; `true` is printed as `1`. Your member pointer is not null, so you get `1`. This is different from normal pointers, which are implicitly converted to `void *` and printed as addresses, but member pointers cannot be converted to `void *` so the only applicable overload of `operator<<` is the one for `bool`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt#Notes.

Note that technically your `printf` calls have undefined behavior. `%p` takes a `void *` and you're passing it pointers of different types. In normal function calls the automatic conversion from `T *` to `void *` would kick in, but `printf` is a variable-arguments function that provides no type context to its argument list, so you need a manual conversion:

```
printf("%p\n", static_cast<void *>(&(C::c)));
```

---

The relevant part of the standard is **[expr.unary.op]**, saying:

> The result of the unary `&` operator is a pointer to its operand.
>   The operand shall be an lvalue or a *qualified-id*. If the operand is a *qualified-id* naming a non-static or variant member `m` of some class `C` with type `T`, the result has type “pointer to member of class `C` of type `T`” and is a prvalue designating `C​::​m`.
>   Otherwise, if the type of the expression is `T`, the result has type “pointer to `T`” [...]

Comment: @M.M Not if you do it in `foo`. See the rest of my answer.

Comment: ”try to print a pointer with `<<`，it's implicitly converted to a bool"。 I try `int b = 1; std::cout << &b << std::endl;`， it output an address not just 1.

Comment: @M.M The one in `main` is commented out ... or at least it was before you edited OP's code. Now it no longer matches the question. Sigh.

Comment: @M.M That's the second question. The first question is why the output is different for `&C::c` vs `&(C::c)`. (The third question is why the output is different for `printf` vs `cout`.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182309/discussion-between-melpomene-and-m-m).

Comment: I removed my comments, it was not productive

Answer (score 4):

While the expression `&C::c` result in a pointer to member `c` the expression `&(C::c)` yield the address of the member variable `c`. The difference you're seeing in the output is that `std::cout` involve a bool implicit conversion that tells you whether the pointer is null or not.

Since `&C::c` is actually not null is implicitly converted to `bool` with value `true` or `1`

Answer (score 1):

**Q1:** There is special meaning to the syntax of `&` followed by an unparenthesized *qualified-id*.  It means to form a pointer-to-member.   Furthermore, there is no other way to form a pointer-to-member.  This is covered by C++17 [expr.unary.op]/4:

> A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit `&` is used and its operand is a *qualified-id* not enclosed in parentheses. [Note: That is, the expression `&(qualified-id)` , where the *qualified-id* is enclosed in parentheses, does not form an expression of type “pointer to member”. Neither does *qualified-id* [...]

---

**Q3:** In both cases where you write `printf("%p\n", &C::c);`,  `&C::c` is a pointer-to-member.  The `%p` format specifier is only for `void *` so this causes undefined behaviour, and the program output is meaningless.

The code `cout << &C::c;` outputs a pointer-to-member via `operator<<(bool val)`, since there is implicit conversion from pointer-to-member to `bool` (with result `true` in all cases), see [conv.bool]/1.

For further discussion of how to print a pointer-to-member, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7827240/1505939).

---

**Q2:** The code `&(C::c)` does not form a pointer-to-member as explained above.

Now, the code `C::c` is in the grammatical category *id-expression*. (Which is *qualified-id* and *unqualified-id*). An *id-expression* has some restrictions on its use, [expr.prim.id]/1:

> An id-expression that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
> - as part of a class member access in which the object expression refers to the member’s class or a class derived from that class, or
> - to form a pointer to member (7.6.2.1), or
> - if that id-expression denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.

When we are inside the `C::foo` function, the first of those bullet points applies. The code is the same as `&c` but with unnecessary qualification. This has type `int *`. You could output this with `std::cout << &(C::c);` which would show a memory address, the address of `this->c`.

When we are in the `main` function , none of the three bullet points apply and therefore the `&(C::c)` is ill-formed.

Comment: Re *this situation seems to be intended as "otherwise indicated":* The n4659 draft explicitly says so in the section about unary operators, 8.3.1/4: *A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit & is used and its operand is a qualified-id **not enclosed
in parentheses.** [Note: That is, the expression &(qualified-id), where the qualified-id is enclosed in
parentheses, does not form an expression of type “pointer to member”. ...]*

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider thanks, I overlooked that paragraph. Updated now

Answer (score 0):

First, you can not access the `int c` by using `&(C::c)` outside a class. `&(C::c)` means the memory address of "`c` of instance `C`", somewhat `&(this->c)` here. However your `c` is not a static member of class `C` and there is no `C` instance. You can not access `int x = C::c` outside, either.

So you see an error with:

```
//    printf("%p\n", &(C::c));   // compile error, invalid use of non-static data member 'C::c'
```

If you have a `static int c`, then `C::c` outside the class is OK, because no instance is needed here.

And let's run

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

class C
{
    public:
        void foo() {
            printf("%p, %p, this=%p\n", &C::c, &(C::c), this);
        }
        int a;
        int c;
};

int main(void)
{
    C co;
    co.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0x4, 0x7ffee78e47f4, this=0x7ffee78e47f0
// 0x4 + this == 0x7ffee78e47f4
// see reference
```

And for `std::out`: the `<< &C::c` is implicit-casted to `bool`, so `true` is `1` you saw. You can treat `&C::c` as `an offset of c in C`, it is unusable without a `C` instance.

That's all.

Some reference: [C++: Pointer to class data member "::*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member)

Full description: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer

Comment: In `C::c`, the `C` can only be a class or namespace name (never an instance)