# Scope Resolution Precedence

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

Let us suppose to have the following code:

```
struct Foo {
  int _data;
};

struct Bar : public Foo {
  int* bar() {
    return &Foo::_data;  // <--- Compiler ERROR!
  }
};
```

The expression `&Foo::_data` is evaluated as `int Foo::*` (i.e., `int`-pointer to a member of the class `Foo`). Therefore, the return statement generates a compiler error because there is no implicit cast conversion.

[Godbolt Snippet Here](https://godbolt.org/z/oSciUh).

Of course, it is easy to fix this: `return &(Foo::_data);`.
Indeed, my intent is to return a pointer to the variable `_data`.

In accordance with the [C++ precedence operator table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the `operator::` should have higher precedence than `operator&`.

My question is: why without parenthesization it seems `operator&` to have higher precedence?

---

**Note**: The compiler error seems to be consistent across different compilers and versions. So I am probably missing something :)

**Note**: I am not interested in how to fix the problem (I have already proposed a solution in the question, or just using `_data`). I more interested to understand why my assumption is not true.

Comment: `_data` is a non-`static` data member. So `&Foo::_data` is a member pointer, not an `int*`.

Comment: Is this a follow-up to [SO: What's the difference between &C::c and &(C::c)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52940237/7478597)?